# Is it a bug? Or an error? Or a wrong query?

Tags: mysql, view, xampp

I have a problem about query in mysql. I made 2 tables, tables1 and table 2. In table1 there is 2 rows data, its same in table2 where it have 2 rows data, and every table have 3 fields. In this case, I want to make view and this a query :

```
create view point as select table2.field2 from table1, table2;
```

I think it will show data in table2 where it have 2 rows data. But the result is showing 4 rows data where every 2 rows is a same data.
When im trying delete 1 row in table1, its mean delete 1 data, and i try input the query like above. The result is correct, its showing 2 rows data in table2. Why it correct when in table1 have 1 row data, and didnt when table1 have 2 rows data. Please how to resolve it? Or its my wrong query.

Comment: You dont have any join conditions in your `from` or `where` clause. Essentially what you're performing is a Cartesian join where there is a row will be displayed for each row in every other table in your `from` clause. Essentially what your seeing is 2 rows * 1 rows = 2 rows. 2 rows * 2 rows = 4 rows. You need to add a join condition for your tables such as linking a primary key to a foreign key.

Comment: Thank before. Now I know when you show the count like your example above. But actually, my 2 tables there isnt any condition to linking. I just want take a values in tables2 and table1 with result in new view whenever it a new field in view too. Now I remember, using view must there relation between 2 tables or more. Thank Rook.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `implicit cross join` between these two tables.

Let's say `table1` has `m` rows and `table2` has `n` rows.

Then

`SELECT * FROM table1,table2` **will return `m*n` rows.**

The above query is equivalent to this:

`SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2`.

If you want to get all rows from `table1` and `table2` keeping in mind that I don't want duplicates then you need to use `UNION`.

So, you might be looking for this query:

```
 CREATE VIEW point AS 
 SELECT table2.field2 from table2 
 UNION 
 SELECT table1.field2 from table1
```

**Note:**

If you want to allow duplicate values in your final result set then use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` like below:

```
CREATE VIEW point AS 
SELECT table2.field2 from table2 
UNION ALL
SELECT table1.field2 from table1
```

Comment: I was trying that, but union is merge 2 select methods to be one select method and ignoring multiple record data.

Comment: yes `UNION` actually merges the results emerging from these two separate queries removing duplicates. Just in case if you want to allow duplicates then use `UNION ALL` instead.